# Automatic binding redirection replacing the entire App.config file

Tags: c#, build, visual-studio-2022, app-config, assembly-binding-redirect

I added an App.config file to my C# project and it has a lot in there: appSettings, connectionStrings, entityFramework, system.net mailSettings, etc. etc.

When I build the project, the resulting `<assemblyname>.exe.config` file is a **completely different file**: *Not a single thing* in my source App.config is there! All that's in the file generated by the build are a few automatically generated assembly binding redirects.

The App.config file is added to the project by default with Build Action = None and Copy to Output Directory = Do not copy; I tried changing it to Copy if newer and Copy always — didn't change the resulting built file.

I took those automatically generated `<assemblyBinding>` from the *.exe.config file and manually added them to my source App.config, see if that would stop Visual Studio's build from overwriting my whole App.config — also made no difference.

Closed Visual Studio, deleted the .vs folder, tried again — same results.

Why would Visual Studio totally *ignore* my project's App.config file and generate it's own .exe.config that doesn't copy anything from the original??

Most importantly, how do I get VS to *stop* doing that?

Update - more info: The project that has the App.config is a Windows Service, on .NET Framework 4.8. I have tried deleting all obj/bin folders as well and when I build, the same thing happens every time.

Comment: After maybe a dozen iterations of trying the same things in different order — close/reopen VS, delete the obj & bin folders, delete the .vs folder, try both Release and Debug builds, one build finally worked and produced a *.exe.config files whose contents matched my project's App.config

Comment: So while my immediate issue is resolved, I never found any clue as to the CAUSE. 
If/when this happens again, it might still cost me hours to get the problem to go away again.

Comment: Have you gone to the VS developer community to give feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details on the type of Project you are trying to build and also which version of .NET you are using?

Ensure you have the latest version of Visual Studio 2022 installed. You can also try deleting the contents in "bin" and "obj" directories and re-build the project. Additionally double-check that you do not have any unwanted configuration transformation extensions active.

Also check if there are any Pre/Post-Build events that would be interfering with the correct App.config being loaded.

**Update:** Investigating further, unfortunately this seems to be an issue that has been present for some time in Visual Studio which has not been addressed or properly resolved:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/applicationexeconfig-being-overwritten-during-buil/610276

A post by Cailin Spain in that thread suggests the following :

> Update: I am now using a new PC with a fresh install of Visual Studio
> and have all the settings as before (the same as the rest of my team)
> and I am still getting this issue, so that's now 3 PC's in our team
> with this problem. I am unable to run my application without using a
> nasty work around (**post build step to overwrite the exe.config with
> the app.config contents**), other people are reporting this same
> problem, so please continue to investigate.

Comment: Has no .config transforms i.e. no difference between Debug or Release builds, and the project has no pre- or post-build events.

Comment: Investigating further, unfortunately this seems to be an issue that has been present for some time in Visual Studio which has not been addressed or properly resolved: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/applicationexeconfig-being-overwritten-during-buil/610276?viewtype=solutions. The post by Cailin Spain in that thread suggests to create "post build step to overwrite the exe.config with the app.config contents".

Comment: That is disappointing that this has been happening for at least three releases of VS with no fix. Thank CIO for finding that.